# WCF service - could not retrieve the service binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We have a simple IIS service just hosting one method via https. The service can be consumed and used w/ SOAPUI and it connects and works just fine. However, we have a client on another network who's consuming our IIS service endpoint and trying to use the service, but the client server is reporting an error:

> Could not retrieve the Service Binding

I have no idea what this means exactly and why it works just fine through another network, but fails on another. Does anyone know what I might chase down to solve this error on the failing server. Maybe there's something I need to change in the service, not sure. Thanks.

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="basicHttpBinding_eLink" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
                    <security mode="Transport" >
                        <transport clientCredentialType= "None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <mexHttpsBinding>
                <binding name="secureMexBinding" />
            </mexHttpsBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="eLink.PublishActionWebService">
                <endpoint 
                    address="" 
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                    bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_eLink" 
                    contract="eLink.IService"/>
                <endpoint 
                    address="mex" 
                    binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
                    bindingConfiguration="secureMexBinding" 
                    contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
            </service>
        </services>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You definitely have an issue - inside your `<bindings>`, you have an opening `<basicHttpBinding>` tag, but the closing tag is `</customBinding>` - that doesn't go together.....

Comment: Tnx, that isn't the problem though. I removed the customBinding section for this illustration only because it wasn't related and must I have deleted the ending  basicHttpBinding tag by accident. I've updated the example. The client has the same binding error even using the above example w/ the correct tags. I'm suspecting the client is the problem though since I can use SOAPUI to consume and use the service just fine.

Comment: @Wildview Please review my answer and let me know if it solves your issue, if to please mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will let you know tomorrow when I deploy it. The Protocol scheme doesn't usually require the binding configuration since it just uses the anonymous binding configuration for the https protocol, but maybe this will resolve it since maybe the anonymous setting doesn't implement the transport mode which I need, not sure. I'll mark it as solved if it works. Tnx.

Comment: there may be some issues in client network, firewall. and so on.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to the late reply, but this didn't resolve my problem. I'll have to keep looking for a solution. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the bindingconfiguration in your `<protocolMapping>` node since you have a named binding being referenced in your endpoint.

From:

```
<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
```

to:

```
<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_eLink" />
```